# Web service client call in NetBeans ends with error 400

Tags: java, web-services, soap, netbeans

i have project in java 7 - Netbeans (8.0.2) on Windows 7 using generated Web service client (SOAP, jax-ws, METRO 2.0).
Web service client consumes service and if call takes less then 2 minutes long. Its fine. However i need to increase this time (10 mins required). This is not problem with service, because i get correct result in .Net project and SoapUi as well with the same request.
There has to be something to set up in Netbeans to avoid this.

Thanks for advice

> I 26, 2015 7:52:55 ODP.
> [com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.PolicyConfigParser]  parse INFO: WSP5018:
> Loaded WSIT configuration from file:
> file:/C:/Users/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/META-INF/wsit-client.xml.
>
> processing time: 120.071282081 s

```
com.sun.xml.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server sent HTTP status code 400: Bad Request
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:183)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:93)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:133)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:629)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:588)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:573)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:470)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:319)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:157)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:109)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:89)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:140)
```